# extract fixed effects from formula

Tags: r

If I have a formula of the form

```r
formula <- mpg ~ wt | cyl + am
```

How can I extract the fixed effects (i.e., what goes at the right of the `|` in a safe way?

I tried

```r
fe <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(formula[[3]][[3]]), split = " + "))
fe <- fe[fe !=  "+"]
```

This does not seem to be very reliable

I just need to obtain a vector or the form `c("cyl", "am")`

Answer (score 2):

Use the Formula package.  The part after | is the 2nd part of the right hand side so specify the argument rhs = 2.

```
library(Formula)

all.vars(formula(Formula(formula), lhs = 0, rhs = 2))
## [1] "cyl" "am"
```

Comment: good solution!! the only "bad" part is that it returns a warning `Warning message:
In is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20 :  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)`

Comment: It did not occur when I tried it with an older version of Formula but on the latest version of Formula it did occur; however, when I tried it again on a fresh R session there was no warning.  Try it again on a fresh session just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm a bit confused by your question.  According to `vignette("lmer", package = "lme4")`:

- The left hand side of the bar `|` defines a random effects formula.
- The right hand side of the bar `|` defines a grouping structure.

That is, the variables on the right represent not fixed effects but grouping variables for random effects.  It is also not standard to use the `+` operator in the grouping expression, as you have in `cyl + am`.  That expression should take the form `g1/.../gn`, or otherwise `g1:...:gn`.

If your mixed effects formula is really `ff <- mpg ~ wt | cyl + am`, then I guess we would say this:

- The corresponding fixed effects formula is `mpg ~ 1`, specifying no fixed effects terms.

  ```r
  > ff.nb <- lme4::nobars(ff)
  > ff.nb
  mpg ~ 1
  > labels(terms(ff.nb))
  character(0)
  ```
- There is one random effects term `wt | cyl + am` with corresponding formula `~wt` and grouping `cyl + am`.  However, the grouping is potentially not meaningful, at least not to **lme4**.

  ```r
  > ff.fb <- lme4::findbars(ff)
  [[1]]
  wt | cyl + am
  > bar <- ff.fb[[1L]]
  > labels(terms(reformulate(deparse(bar[[2L]]))))
  [1] "wt"
  > labels(terms(reformulate(deparse(bar[[3L]]))))
  [1] "cyl" "am"
  ```

Had we defined `ff` more sensibly as `ff <- mpg ~ wt | am/cyl`, then the last line above would give:

```r
> labels(terms(reformulate(deparse(bar[[3L]]))))
[1] "cyl" "am:cyl"
```

indicating that the random slope with respect to `wt` varies among the levels of `am` and among the levels of `cyl` within `am`.

Comment: excellent point!! in lfe and fixest, something like `y ~ a + b | c` means that `c` is the fixed effects / varying intercept variable

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Since the **fixest** syntax is nonstandard (not really following `?formula`), I'm not sure that any of the answers so far will be robust.  They both clearly work for `cyl + am`, but I'm not so sure about the more complicated cases using the operators mentioned in `?fixest::feols` ...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are different syntaxes for fixed effects between packages (cf @MikaelJagan's answer). However, you could use the package [`insight`](https://easystats.github.io/insight/index.html), which aims at providing a consistent interface to extract information, data, etc. for many models:

```r
library(fixest)
library(insight)

mod <- feols(mpg ~ wt | cyl + am, mtcars)

find_terms(mod)
#> $response
#> [1] "mpg"
#> 
#> $conditional
#> [1] "wt"
#> 
#> $cluster
#> [1] "cyl" "am"

find_predictors(mod)
#> $conditional
#> [1] "wt"
#> 
#> $cluster
#> [1] "cyl" "am"
```